# ¿Cómo indicar las restricciones PK y FK en los campos de una Tabla en Oracle.?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo la siguiente consulta en `oracle` para indicar si un campo es PK, FK, o ninguno de ellos, lo indico con (' ') dentro de la cláusula `CASE`.

```
-- CONSULTA PARA MOSTRAR (PK y FK)
----------------------------------
select  a.OWNER,        
        a.table_name, 
        a.column_name,
        case when b.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='P' then 'X' else ' ' end PK,
        case when b.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='R' then 'X' else ' ' end FK

from  ALL_CONS_COLUMNS a inner join ALL_CONSTRAINTS b
        on a.CONSTRAINT_name=b.CONSTRAINT_NAME

where a.OWNER='Usuario' AND a.TABLE_NAME='MiTabla'
order by a.TABLE_NAME;
```

El problema es que no me lista todos los campos que tiene la tabla, por que las tablas consultadas pues no aparecen todos campos. He intentado usar el `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` junto a las anteriores sin éxito. Cualquier sugerencia sería de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En efecto, para que obtengas todas las columnas, necesitas que tu consulta use `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` y luego hacer un `LEFT JOIN` a las tablas `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` y `ALL_CONSTRAINTS`.

Aquí te dejo una manera de obtener la información deseada:

```
select tc.owner, tc.table_name, tc.column_name,
       nvl(max(case when c.constraint_type = 'P' then 'X' end), ' ') PK,
       nvl(max(case when c.constraint_type = 'R' then 'X' end), ' ') FK
  from all_tab_columns tc
  left join (select c.owner, c.table_name, c.constraint_type, cc.column_name
               from all_constraints c
               join all_cons_columns cc
                 on cc.owner = c.owner
                and cc.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
                and cc.table_name = c.table_name
              where c.constraint_type in ('P', 'R')) c
    on c.owner = tc.owner
   and c.table_name = tc.table_name
   and c.column_name = tc.column_name
 where tc.owner = 'Usuario'
   and tc.table_name = 'MiTabla'
 group by tc.owner, tc.table_name, tc.column_name, tc.column_id
 order by tc.column_id
```

Comment: Gracias, me podrías explicar por que agregaste la función `nvl()` y `max()`? por que he estado probando sin estas funciones y pues el código funciona igual.

Comment: El `group by` junto con el `max` es necesario para manejar el caso donde una misma columna participa en ambos un PK y un FK. O, aunque mas raro, pero posible, en el caso cuando una misma columna participa en mas de un FK. Sin el `group by` y `max`, obtendrías registros duplicados. Si no vistes diferencia, es porque no se dio este caso con las tablas que probastes.

Comment: El uso de `nvl` es mas difícil de explicar, pero es una consecuencia de usar `max`. Como uso `max`, si uso `then 'X' else ' ' end` en vez de `nvl`, entonces el orden lógico de los caracteres `X` y `' '` afecta el resultado final. Si decidieras cambiar el `' '` por otro caracter, sin querer pudieras estar cambiando la forma como `max` interpreta los resultados. Para evitar esta dependencia sutil, me parece mejor práctica usar `nvl` para que la consulta funcione correctamente sin importar los caracteres que uses para presentar los resultados. Espero que tenga sentido lo que digo :)